# ponerle protecion contra HWID a mi aplicacion de tal manera que solo se ejecute en mi pc

Tags: python

Desarollé cierta aplicación en tkinter pero quiero que solo se ejecute en mi pc verificando el HWID de la misma, de tal manera que si me la roban no se pueda ejecutar en ninguna otra pc. Lo otro es que si yo decidiera darsela a alguien haria los cambios correspondientes en cuanto a esta protenccion contra hwid y la pudiera regalar a un amigo,,,,no se declarando el hwid de ese amigo,o creando algun tipo de licencia para las pc que yo decido que la aplicacion abra,la aplicacion solo se ejecutara en sitemas windows,no se si me hago entender,,saludos

He intentado codigos como este pero no me funcionan para obtener ese HWID

```
import subprocess
x = subprocess.check_output('wmic csproduct get UUID')
print(x)
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para que aprendas a formular una buena pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: me parece que la pregunta esta bien clara,,ponerle protecion contra HWID a mi aplicacion de tal manera que solo se ejecute en mi pc

Comment: Has realizado una investigación previa a formular tu pregunta, que has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando llamas `subprocess.check_output(args)`, te devuelve un objeto `bytes`, no `str` (texto). Para convertirlo, basta con hacer:

```
x = str(x, encoding="utf8")
```

Adicionalmente, debes modificar tu x (o tu print, en este caso) de forma que agarre la segunda línea, dado que el comando devuelve dos líneas:

> C:\Users\Usuario> wmic csproduct get UUID
>
> UUID
>
> XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX

Para obtener la segunda línea, lo separamos por `\n` (newlines) y agarramos el index 1.

```
print(x.split('\n')[1])
```

Nota que esto no es para nada seguro, ya que Python está enfocado en ser transparente, y cualquier persona podría muy fácilmente eliminar esa línea de check. Para mayor información de cómo proteger tu código puedes chequear [esta guía](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Asking%20for%20Help/How%20do%20you%20protect%20Python%20source%20code%3F).